# Why is my program taking so long to execute/is there something wrong with the way I completed the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on this problem:

For various given positive integers N > 3, find two primes, A and B such that N is the average
(mean) of A and B. That is, N should be equal to (A + B)/2.
Recall that a prime number is an integer P > 1 which is only divisible by 1 and P. For example,
2, 3, 5, 7, 11 are the first few primes, and 4, 6, 8, 9 are not prime numbers.

**Input Specification**

The first line of input is the number T (1 ≤ T ≤ 1000), which is the number of test cases. Each of
the next T lines contain one integer N (4 ≤ Ni ≤ 1 000 000, 1 ≤ i ≤ T).
For 6 of the available 15 marks, all N < 1 000.

**Output Specification**

The output will consist of T lines. The *ith* line of output will contain two integers, A and B,
separated by one space. It should be the case that N = (A + B)/2 and that A and B are prime
numbers.
If there are more than one possible A and B for a particular N, output any such pair. The order
of the pair Ai and Bi does not matter.
It will be the case that there will always be at least one set of values A and B for any given N.

Here is my code:

```
numofInput = int(input())
primeSet = []
for i in range(numofInput):
    line = input()
    primeSet.append(line)
print("Starting...")
for i in primeSet:
    for j in range(4, 1000):
        if (j / 2 != 0) and (j / 3 != 0) and (j / 5 != 0) and (j / 7!= 0) and (j / 11 != 0):
            num1 = j
            for k in range(4, 1000):
                if (k / 2 != 0) and (k / 3 != 0) and (k / 5 != 0) and (k / 7!= 0) and (k / 11 != 0):
                    num2 = k
                    if ((num1 + num2) / 2) == i:
                        print(num1 + num2)
                    else:
                        continue
```

Now I don't really know what's going on and would appreciate any help given! Thanks in advance!

New For loop Code:

```
for i in primeSet:
 
    for j in range(4, 1000000):

         if (j / 2 != 0) and (j / 3 != 0) and (j / 5 != 0) and (j / 7!= 0) and (j / 11 != 0):

             num1 = j

             num2 = i - j

             if ((num1 + num2) / 2) == i

                 print(num1, num2)

             else:

                 continue
```

Comment: You loop over all possible prime `j` values, and for each one you loop over all possible prime `k` values, and for each one of those you check if the two values average to the given `i`.  *This is utterly insane* -  for a given `j`, there is only one `k` value that can even possibly work (it's `i + i - j`); you should check that one value, rather than looping over values that are guaranteed not to work.

Comment: 1) you want primeSet to contain integers not strings, so need `line = int(input())`, 2) The largest prime needed will be < 2M, so use a fast algorithm to find all primes up to 1M (i.e. Sieve of Eratosthenes) and place into a set, i.e. prime set, 3) To solve for an N, loop over the prime set looking for A in the prime set and a 2*N-A also in the prime set.(i.e. the N-A will be B).

Comment: Why are you dividing instead of doing modulo? Since you're dividing, _of course_ your division will _always_ be `!= 0`

Comment: @jasonharper Is this what you meant? [Code is in my main post as its not formatting correctly here].This code still does not work (it does not output anything). Can you clarify what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Demonstration using Sieve of Eratosenes

**Code**

```
def find_primes(n):
    ''' Use Sieve of Eratosthenes to find primes up to n 
        Code from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Using_set_lookup
    '''
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            yield i
            multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))
            
def find_a_b(n, primes = set(find_primes(2000000))):
    '''
        finds two numbers a, b such that a and b are primes and a + b == 2*n
        Default argument primes will be initialized once the first time function is called
    ''' 
    n = 2*n # avoid division by looking for A + B = 2*n 
            # rather than n = (A + B)/2
    for A in primes:
        if A < n and n - A in primes:
            return A, n - A  # solution as a tuple
    return None  # No solution


# Test Run on test cases (using numbers 5 to 100)
numofInput = int(input())
primeSet = []
for i in range(numofInput):
    line = int(input())  # OP code missing int conversion
    primeSet.append(line)
    
for i in primeSet:
    sol = find_a_b(i)
    if sol:
        # There was a solution
        print(f'{i} == ({sol[0]} + {sol[1]})/2')
```

**Input**

```
2
5
6
```

**Output**

```
5 == (3 + 7)/2
6 == (5 + 7)/2
```

**Alternative Prime Finding Algorithm**

```
def find_primes_prime_division(n):
    ' find primes from 2 up to n '
    primes = [2, 3] # seed with first two primes
    test = primes[-1]
    while test < n:
        test += 2
        if all(test % p for p in primes):
            primes.append(test)  # test is prime since no divisors
    return primes
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Sieve of Eratosense algorithm, but it seems like the key to this problem. However, I am kind of confused when looking at the code for it. I went on the website you provided for the algorithm code and found a way to use the algorithm with an array, however I still did not fully understand the code.

My question is that is there a way to do this without the Sieve of Eratosenes?

Comment: @ChillDude4763--The Sieve of Eratosense is one of the most efficient algorithms for finding small prime numbers i.e. up to 10 million or so.  There are many description of the algorithm online such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20sieve%20of,up%20to%20any%20given%20limit.&text=One%20of%20a%20number%20of,find%20primes%20in%20arithmetic%20progressions.) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V08g_lkKj6Q&t=188s).  Does this help?

Comment: @ChillDude4763--Since you were confused by the Sieve method, I added an alternative prime finding algorithm to the post which is simpler than the Sieve method.  It basically creates a growing list of primes.  A number is prime if it's not divisible by a number in the list, so is added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a variant of the Golbach conjecture that states that all even numbers can be expressed as the sum of two primes.  So, if you find two primes that add up to 2N, you have an answer.

The fastest way to find those is to build a set of primes and, for each of them check if the difference with 2N is also a prime.  Using a set will make this verification extremely fast.

So you will need a prime number generator (e.g. using the sieve of Eratosthenes) to build your set of primes and then just run through them up to N.

```
def genPrimes(N):
    isPrime = [True]*(N+1)
    yield 2
    for p in range(3,N+1,2):
        if not isPrime[p]: continue
        yield p
        isPrime[p*p::p] = (False for _ in range(p*p,N+1,p))


def goldbach(Even):
    primes = {*genPrimes(Even)} # set of primes that can add up to Even
    for p in primes:
        if 2*p>Even: break    # only primes up to half of Even (avoids duplicates)
        if Even-p in primes:  # when the difference with Even is also a prime
            yield p,Even-p    # return the two primes
```

Example use:

```
N = 50
print(*goldbach(2*N))

# (3, 97) (11, 89) (17, 83) (29, 71) (41, 59) (47, 53)
```

Comment: Can you further clarify the `if 2 * p > Even` and the rest of the code after that? I'm not sure I understand? Sorry about that!

Comment: While going through primes, we eventually get to half of the target sum.  After that the values of p have already been seen as E-p in the previous primes.  That's why we exit the loop. For example, if Even is 24, once we get to p=12, we don't nee to go further because the next prime (13) will have  a difference of 11, which we have already checked at that point.

Comment: The rest of the code tries to find a matching pair of primes. If Even is 24, we will start with 2 + 22 (22 is not a prime), then 3 + 21 (21 is not a prime),  5+19 (19 is a prime so we output 5,19), 7+17 (output 7,17), 11+13 (output 11,13), then we have reached half and break.  Otherwise we would get 13+11 which we've already seen as 11,13.